# How to get external I/O on a windows phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Is there a solution for Windows Phones to interact with external I/O? Something like this Android solution... https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12633

I want to be able to access analog/digital sensors, PWM, I2C, etc. My intention is to use a Windows Phone (8.1 for now, 10 soon) for robotics and other gadgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to communicate to other devices is via Bluetooth, WiFi or NFC. 
Another possibility would be to send data via the audio jack, but this is pretty ugly :/

Comment: :( So far the only limitation I've come across with Windows Phone. After some searching, I think I'll go with making my own I/O break out using an Arduino with a Bluetooth module. Hopefully I can get something like this article to work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872388/can-i-use-the-bluetooth-serial-port-in-windows-phone-7-1-and-up

Comment: Bluetooth LE works perfect; used this in other projects as well :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use this feature, the device requires USB Type-C support. The upcoming Lumias are reported to have this.